# When will KDE 5.27.6 available for Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, kde

At the moment it is still 5.27.4 and no further update.

Comment: Does Kubuntu not updates KDE out of the box with bugfixes? :-/ This is weird...

Comment: @Ezh avoid jumping to conclusions or calling names. Kubuntu is not a rolling release, and is maintained entirely by volunteers. Right now, they are testing 5.27.6 in pre-release which will become Ubuntu 23.10 in three months. If you want to test backporting 5.27.6 to 23.04, then contact the Kubuntu volunteers and offer that help.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu does not always have the latest version of all the packages for [certain reasons](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software#:%7E:text=Two%20reasons.,willy%2Dnilly%20to%20avoid%20breakage). Your version of Kubuntu will possibly never have the update. The daily builds of the next version of Kubuntu (i.e. 23.10) already has 5.27.6, and will have a later version by the time it is released.

---

However, you can install the latest KDE Packages in Ubuntu 23.04 with the KDE backports ppa.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

Comment: Does Kubuntu not updates KDE out of the box with bug fixes. It's a same version (5.27), not a major update (5.28/6.0). :-/ This is really weird...

Comment: @Ezh They do that for LTS releases (over span of 5 years), but not for interim releases